# Pairing terms from two tables and inserting into one table (Hard)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables that already contain rows which are:

TBL_TESTER_LIST

```
id  tester_type tester_name
1      LMX         LMX-01
2      LMX         LMX-04
3      LMX         LMX-05
4      LMX         LMX-06
```

TBL_DEVICE_LIST

```
id  tester_type
2     LMX
3     LMX
4     LMX
5     LMX
```

and finally TBL_QUALIFIED_TESTER

```
id   tester_type device_id tester_id
1     LMX           7       1
2     LMX           8       1                                   
3     LMX           9       1                               
4     LMX           10      1
```

What I want to do is to get an id in TBL_TESTER_LIST, let's say id 2, get all the tester_type that are 'LMX' in TBL_DEVICE_LIST, and insert these values into TBL_QUALIFIED_TESTER.

Just for clarification this would be the result of TBL_QUALIFIED_TESTER (together with the data that already exists):

```
id   tester_type device_id tester_id
1     LMX           7       1
2     LMX           8       1                                   
3     LMX           9       1                               
4     LMX           10      1
5     LMX           1       2
6     LMX           2       2
7     LMX           3       2
8     LMX           4       2
```

I'm going to be using this query for a webapp so is there any possible way to do it in a single/simple statement? I'm using MYSQL to try it out first by the way.

Just in case you would like to know why I would like to pair, reason being would be if the user select this tester, then all the tester names associated or paired with it would show up.

EDIT: In TBL_QUALIFIED TESTER table, tester_type and device_id should be from TBL_DEVICE_LIST, and tester_id should be from TBL_TESTER_LIST.

Comment: i dont see how your example output matches up with your sample data -- there are only 4 ids in your device_list, yet there are 8 of them in your expected output?

Comment: @pala_ That's just some of the data that is already in just for a sample. If I were to put the whole table in, it would be 500+ rows.

Comment: not the whole data, but preferably some data that lines up with the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand, it seems like you just want to `join` the two tables together.

```
select dl.tester_type, dl.id as `device_id`, tl.id as `tester_id`
  from tbl_tester_list tl
    inner join tbl_device_list dl
      on tl.tester_type = dl.tester_type
```

And you can populate the (pre-existing) `tbl_qualified_tester` like this:

```
insert into tbl_qualified_tester(tester_type, device_id, tester_id)
select dl.tester_type, dl.id as `device_id`, tl.id as `tester_id`
  from tbl_tester_list tl
    inner join tbl_device_list dl
      on tl.tester_type = dl.tester_type
```